# rails devise This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have used the following route

```
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', registration: 'signup', sign_up: 'signup'}

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get 'signup', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
  end
```

As of above when I run localhost:3000 it will show registration page. But once I login/register using devise gem it redirect again back to root path so causing the following redirect loop How can I customize devise to redirect specific page after login.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this with devise, and [the devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) has around ten or so listed.

This page on the devise wiki should help: [How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

This page should help as well [How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign in and sign out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out).

I've also used the solution detailed on this wiki page: [How To: Redirect back to current page after sign in, sign out, sign up, update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)